# Touchpad horizontal scrolling and Areas setting don't work in Gnome on Wayland

Tags: linux, gnome, touchpad, scrolling, wayland

I'm accessing a CentOS 8 VM (VMware) via Nomachine NX from a MacBook Pro running macOS 10.15.7. Running Gnome 3.32.2 on Wayland.

Two fingered scrolling works for vertical scrolling, but not for horizontal scrolling. I've set `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad two-finger-scrolling-enabled true`. `gnome-tweaks` doesn't provide a setting for this.

I've set `org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'areas'`which is supposed to allow a click in the middle bottom of touchpad to translate to middle mouse, and a click in the bottom right to translate to a right click. This doesn't work. I've also set this via gnome-tweaks.

```
$ gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad send-events 'enabled'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad natural-scroll false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-to-click false
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad two-finger-scrolling-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad left-handed 'mouse'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method 'areas'
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad speed 0.0
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad tap-and-drag true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad edge-scrolling-enabled true
org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad disable-while-typing true
```

```
# libinput list-devices
...
Device:           VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event3
Group:            3
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: n/a
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   button
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           VirtualPS/2 VMware VMMouse
Kernel:           /dev/input/event2
Group:            3
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      identity matrix
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           NoMachine Input Device
Kernel:           /dev/input/event5
Group:            4
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      identity matrix
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a

Device:           NoMachine Input Device
Kernel:           /dev/input/event6
Group:            5
Seat:             seat0, default
Capabilities:     keyboard pointer 
Tap-to-click:     n/a
Tap-and-drag:     n/a
Tap drag lock:    n/a
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      identity matrix
Scroll methods:   none
Click methods:    none
Disable-w-typing: n/a
Accel profiles:   n/a
Rotation:         n/a
```

Comment: Partially solved the Areas problem. On the MacBook from which I was accessing the VM via NX  I had the touchpad setting as "Secondary click - 2 finger click". Changing it to "Secondary click - click in bottom right corner" I can now get right mouse by clicking in bottom right of touchpad.
Still no middle mouse. Even with setting NX to "Emulate middle mouse button".

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to turn off Natural scrolling on the MacBook (Preferences -> Trackpad -> Scroll direction: Natural).